# Communication between 2 c++ application

Tags: c++, networking

There are 2 c++ applications where one application let say A is reading from an interface device and does some processing and need to provide the data in certain format to an application B. 
I feel this can be done in 2 ways as mentioned below - 
1. I serialize the data structure in app A and write it to a socket. 
2. I inject the packet to an interface.

Please help to evaluate which option would be faster. Or if there is another way to do it faster.

Comment: What do you mean by "inject the packet to an interface"? What is an "interface"?

Comment: What's the target platform?

Comment: Shared memory comes to mind because from your other post I assume you are processing LOTS of data and want to be fast.

Comment: What I mean from "inject on an ethernet interface" is that I will write on an interface using either libpcap or pfring. 

@D Drmmr - Target Platform is Linux 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I inject the packet to an interface."

Anyway, if your 2 applications are or could be on separate machines, go for the socket solution.

If on the same machine, you can implement some type of interprocess communication. I recommend you to use Boost for this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

As far as performance is concern, ideally you want to perform some tests to find out which work better in your scenario. Also, if you're already familiar with sockets, it may be simpler to use them.

Comment: -I am using pthreads library programming.. not the boost one. Is there any prominent difference between them .Yes ultimately I am gonna test it But I thought asking here because lots of expertise are part of this forum.

Comment: The Boost implementation is cross platform and is quite pleasant to use. It seems to be using pthreads under the hood on POSIX systems (from the documentation: "In POSIX systems, Boost.Interprocess uses pthread system calls to implement classes like mutexes, condition variables, etc..."). I am not familiar with pthreads. However, from reading http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html, it seems that it provides a few way to perform what you're looking for.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, would you mind accepting it? Otherwise let me know if I can help...